# Word for when satire is no longer satire

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Is there a word for when a satirical piece of work ceases to be satirical because the concept under scrutiny has now become widely accepted.

Comment: A dead parrot sketch?

Comment: Trump candidacy.

Comment: Try plying us with an example or two.

Comment: Are you referring to **"prophetic"** - as in: ***"Big Brother is watching you"***?

Comment: Obsolete? . . .

Comment: @BrianDonovan I am asking the question because I have just seen the movie [Network](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074958/), which seemed like it would have been satire back in the 70s when it was made. But it hardly seems satirical now.

Comment: @Oldbag I guess that's sort of the word I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Poe's Law (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law) is the closest thing to what you're looking for:

> Poe's law is an Internet adage which states that, without a clear indicator of the author's intent, parodies of extreme views will, to some readers, be indistinguishable from sincere expressions of the parodied views.[1][2][3]